# Merge Row Data in Excel with Text-Values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I've got an Sheet looking like this:

| Name | Fact 1 | Fact 2 | Fact 3 | Fact 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Texas | x |  |  |  |
| Texas |  | x |  |  |
| Texas |  |  | x |  |
| Texas |  |  |  | X |
| Texas |  |  |  |  |
| Ohio | x |  |  |  |
| Ohio |  |  | x |  |

I want to merge those rows to just this:

| Name | Fact 1 | Fact 2 | Fact 3 | Fact 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Texas | x | x | x | X |
| Ohio | x |  | x |  |

How is this possible in Microsoft Excel?

Comment: Try to create a PivotTable based on the original table: rows - **Name**, values - Count for each **Fact**. The table will have values (usually 1) and empty cells - apply the `"x";;` format to them

Answer (score 1):

Regarding to @JohnSUN

Using the Pivot-Table function from Excel will "merge" all the fields and consolidate all the values as "1" if the values will be counted.

Then using just the replace function to "x" the values again does the trick.

Thanks to @JohnSUN